# Nest serializers skips transform step

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model in which I use a JSON field and when I serializer it alone, it works perfectly.  However, when I include it as a nested serializer it doesn't convert from JSON and I am left with a string.

I have tried using transform_fieldname but it doesn't get hit if the serializer is nested.  It gets hit if the serializer is not nested.

I am using the django-jsonfield module in my model.

```
class TopLevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nest = NestedSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelTop
        fields = ('id', 'nest')

class NestedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def transform_options(self, obj, value):
        print 'This doesn't get hit if nested'  
        return json.loads(obj)
    class Meta:
        model = ModelTwo
        fields = ('id', 'options')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifing the depth of the serialization of your relation?

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: I tried specifying the depth on my relation but it didn't help.